# Why doesn't boost::lockfree::spsc_queue have emplace?

Tags: boost, thread-safety, locking, emplace

The regular `std::vector` has `emplace_back` which avoid an unnecessary copy. Is there a reason `spsc_queue` doesn't support this? Is it impossible to do `emplace` with lock-free queues for some reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a boost library implementer nor maintainer, so the rationale behind why not to include an `emplace` member function is beyond my knowledge, but it isn't too difficult to implement it yourself if you really need it.

The `spsc_queue` has a base class of either `compile_time_sized_ringbuffer` or `runtime_sized_ringbuffer` depending on if the size of the queue is known at compilation or not. These two classes maintain the actual buffer used with the obvious differences between a dynamic buffer and compile-time buffer,  but delegate, in this case, their `push` member functions to a common base class - `ringbuffer_base`.

The `ringbuffer_base::push` function is relatively easy to grok:

```
bool push(T const & t, T * buffer, size_t max_size)
{
    const size_t write_index = write_index_.load(memory_order_relaxed);  // only written from push thread
    const size_t next = next_index(write_index, max_size);

    if (next == read_index_.load(memory_order_acquire))
        return false; /* ringbuffer is full */

    new (buffer + write_index) T(t); // copy-construct

    write_index_.store(next, memory_order_release);

    return true;
}
```

An index into the location where the next item should be stored is done with a `relaxed` load (which is safe since the intended use of this class is single producer for the `push` calls) and gets the appropriate next index, checks to make sure everything is in-bounds (with a load-acquire for appropriate synchronization with the thread that calls `pop`) , but the main statement we're interested in is:

```
new (buffer + write_index) T(t); // copy-construct
```

Which performs a placement new copy construction into the buffer. There's nothing inherently thread-unsafe about passing around some parameters to use to construct a `T` directly from viable constructor arguments. I wrote the following snippet and made the necessary changes throughout the derived classes to appropriately delegate the work up to the base class:

```
template<typename ... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T,Args...>::value,bool>
emplace( T * buffer, size_t max_size,Args&&... args)
{
    const size_t write_index = write_index_.load(memory_order_relaxed);  // only written from push thread
    const size_t next = next_index(write_index, max_size);

    if (next == read_index_.load(memory_order_acquire))
        return false; /* ringbuffer is full */

    new (buffer + write_index) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); // emplace

    write_index_.store(next, memory_order_release);

    return true;
}
```

Perhaps the only difference is making sure that the arguments passed in `Args...` can actually be used to construct a `T`, and of course doing the emplacement via `std::forward` instead of a copy construction.